# Is there any way to get source info froum Google Analytics for specific Client ID by API?

Tags: api, google-analytics

Is there any way to get source info from Google Analytics for specific Client ID by API?
Like I can get it using GUI in GA - https://prnt.sc/rdfpo6

PS. Found needed info - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search

Comment: found this link which actually provides needed info - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search

Answer (score 1):

**The Client ID isn't exposed via the API (same with the User ID)**, so instead you want to record the Client ID as a custom dimension:
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/#2-client-id

And then you can query it via the API using `ga:dimensionXX` where `XX` is the dimension index:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#ga:dimensionXX

Comment: You're talking about Analytics Reporting API. You don't have to set up custom dimension anymore, just query ga:clientId. However the question is about retrieving information associated with a specific client ID and that falls under User Activity API.

Comment: Interesting, can you point me to do the doc mentioning how to query Analytics Reporting v4 with ga:clientId? I know it can be done with this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting but I didn't about the main reporting endpoint

Comment: As of today ga:clientId is still not available in Query Explorer or included in official docs yet but works with the main endpoint since later last year https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet